# Is "get away with you" command related with "be/behave yourself"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, idioms

I see in my dictionary that a fool is asked to stop kidding either by the command "be/behave yourself" or "get away [with you]". I am curious to know what is denoted with "with you" in the latter? Does it tell us that person is serious when she it herself, as in the former, or something different?

I see that in English, "yourself" and "proper" stand for "serious and good", likewise if person is good inherently. Now, does "with you" stands for "be good" or "talk you yourself"?

I am looking at these entries

> 1. [get away with you](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=get+away+with+you)
>      [image]
> 2. [be yourself](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=be+yourself)
>      [image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some example phrases using the terms in your question. As written they aren't quite what I think you mean. For example, *be yourself* and *behave yourself* don't mean the same thing. And *get away with you* needs some context. As it is, "with you" seems to refer to the fool.

Comment: @user3169 I am watching this dictionary for [get away with you](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=get+away+with+you) and [be yourself](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=be+yourself) that wonder you so much. All phases are translated to Russian as if they are synonyms.

Comment: At least in the English I speak, *get away with you* is something people very rarely say.  Both *be yourself* and *behave yourself* sound fine, but they mean very different things.  I don't think *be yourself* means "stop kidding around!"

Comment: I am a native English speaker and I have never heard the phrase "get away with you". I HAVE heard "go away" (no "with you") which means something completely different than "be yourself" which is something completely different from "behave yourself".

Answer (score 1):

Get away (with you)! Be yourself! Behave yourself!

These expressions are not interchangeable; each is used in a different sense.

Get away (with you) is old-fashioned and informal in BE that is used in the imperative to express that you don't believe what someone is saying. You can say either Get away! or Get away with you! It means that I don't believe what you are saying.

Be yourself is used to ask someone to act naturally in the way he does, not in the way people want.

Behave yourself means that you should be polite and not be rude or cause trouble.

Comment: My question was more about `with _you_` annex in the first phrase. Can I conclude from your answers that `yourself` in `behave yourself` is not related to `you` in `get away with you`?

Comment: Recognize Evil as Waste, The addressee in all these phrases is the second person.

Comment: The modern informal American English for "Get away with you" is "Get out of here" (or "Get the **** out of here").

Answer (score 0):

"Get away with you!" corresponds to Scots "Havers!" («Вот глупости!») or "[Go] away and boil your head!", said with real or feigned incredulity or disgust. "Get away with you!" is more likely to be said as "away with you!" and is an idiom.

The "with you" can't be translated as «с тобой» or «тобой»; there's no "with" involved.  "Get away with you" would be approximately «Убирайся, дурак!» "Get out of here, fool!".

"Be yourself" is just a poor translation of any of the Russian phrases.  Depending on context, «возьмите себя в руки» could be "pull yourself together"/"get hold of yourself" said to someone who's panicking, or "be your age!" said to someone who's acting immaturely.